# Is it possible, with simple F# pattern matching transformations, to ignore unmatched values without a warning?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, transformation

So, I previously asked this question:

[Can someone help me compare using F# over C# in this specific example (IP Address expressions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820234/can-someone-help-me-compare-using-f-over-c-in-this-specific-example-ip-address)

I was looking at the posted code and I was wondering if this code could be written without it producing a warning:

```
let [|a;b;c;d|] = s.Split [|'.'|]
IP(parseOrParts a, parseOrParts b, parseOrParts c, parseOrParts d)
```

Is it possible to do something for the match _ pattern ot ignore? Without adding in something like Active Patterns? i want to keep the code as simple as possible... can I do this without drastically changing this code?

NOTE: Warning is as follows

> Warning   Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '[|_; _; _; _; _|]' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

Comment: Personally, I would use `System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse` so my code wouldn't die horribly the first time it ran into an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try

```
#nowarn "25"
```

before the partial function.

But of course you're disabling a warning, and I think this turns it off for the whole file. I remember seeing a way to disable warnings for only part of a file, but I can't find it right now.

There is also the compiler option `--nowarn:25`, but this is even worse since it applies to the whole project.

---

To do this the Right Way, you need to replace your two lines with three:

```
match Array.map parseOrParts (s.Split [|'.'|]) with
| [|a;b;c;d|] -> IP(a,b,c,d)
| _ -> failwith "Oh no!"   // preferably, your exception of choice goes here.
```

Comment: Yeah it does the whole file. Not quite what I was looking for, but still good to know!  :)

Comment: In response to your second part: That works, except it wouldn't take the code exactly as you wrote... I change it to: 

    match s.Split[|'.'|] |> Array.map parseOrParts with  \n
    | [|a;b;c;d|] -> IP(a, b, c, d)  \n
    | x -> failwithf "IP was not valid (%A)." x  \n

(Sorry, I can't figure out how to format this comment)

Comment: Yeah, originally missing parens around `(s.Split[|'.'|])`.

Comment: Oops, I wrote this fast without testing. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the warning is telling you that if there are not exactly 4 elements after the String.Split call, you'll get a [MatchFailureException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353648.aspx).

As others have said, the best way to get rid of the warning is

```
match s.Split(...) with
| [| a; b; c; d |] -> blah(a,b,c,d)
| _ -> raise <| new Exception("Expected exactly 4 parts") // or whatever
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that you wrote "without adding things like Active Patterns", but I'll post a solution that uses them anyway. They are a perfect match for problems like this and they are a pretty standard F# feature, so there is really no reason why you would want to avoid them. Using active patterns here makes the code definitely more readable.

*(If you're F# beginner than I can understand why you want to start with a simple solution - anyway, this may be a good motivation for you to learn active patterns eventually :-), they are not as difficult as they may appear for the first look)*

You can define an active patter that matches if the string is formatted as an IP address (consisting of four substrings separated by "."):

```
let (|IPString|_|) (s:string) =
  match s.Split('.') with
  | [|a;b;c;d|] -> Some(a, b, c, d) // Returns 'Some' denoting a success
  | _ -> None                       // The pattern failed (string was ill-formed)

match s with 
| IPString(a, b, c, d) ->  
    // Matches if the active pattern 'IPString' succeeds and gives
    // us the four parts of the IP address (as strings)
    (parseOrParts a, parseOrParts b, parseOrParts c, parseOrParts d)
| _ -> failwith "wrong format"
```

This is the proper way that allows you to handle the case when the string is incorrect. You can of course define a version that never fails (and returns for example 0.0.0.0 if the string is ill-formed):

```
// This active pattern always succeeds, so it doesn't include the "|_|" part 
// in the name. In both branches we return a tuple of four values.
let (|IPString|) (s:string) =
  match s.Split('.') with
  | [|a;b;c;d|] -> (a, b, c, d)
  | _ -> ("0", "0", "0", "0")

let (IPString(a, b, c, d)) = str
(parseOrParts a, parseOrParts b, parseOrParts c, parseOrParts d)
```

I think most of the people would agree that this is more readable. Of course, if you want to write something simple just for a single purpose script, then you can just ignore the warning, but for anything larger, I'd prefer active patterns.

Comment: Your first active pattern seems rather pointless, as you could just use `match` directly. About the only thing it offers is the abstraction `IPString`, which isn't really what the question was about.